# Codename One - iOS build error at export step

Tags: ios, codenameone

I'm currently developing a Codename One app using the new Google maps CN1lib, the cn1Filechooser, cn1JSON and the connectivity cn1lib. 
All Android builds work fine, but iOS builds crash since last week...

I've got the error "IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 3" after the success of building the Archive, so the Export Failed and I can't deploy my app on iOS.

I've already renewed all my iOS certificate via the CN1 certificate generator, nothing has changed...

I've post the CN1 build hints and the end of the last error log from the build server, if anyone has an id of what can cause the crash, it would save me :)

Here is the end of the CN1 build server log:

```
** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **

Executing: echo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath eCustMobileProto1.xcarchive -exportPath /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8025404516907269688xxx/result -exportOptionsPlist /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/export55737858647735041.plist -verbose PROVISIONING_PROFILE=8526205d-efbf-48ac-9ea4-bd8390742199 CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX KEYCHAIN=/Users/administrator/Library/Keychains/temp1492092940342.keychain CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS=/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/Entitlements1862900839419593581.plist /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath eCustMobileProto1.xcarchive -exportPath /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8025404516907269688xxx/result -exportOptionsPlist /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/export55737858647735041.plist -verbose PROVISIONING_PROFILE=8526205d-efbf-48ac-9ea4-bd8390742199 CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX KEYCHAIN=/Users/administrator/Library/Keychains/temp1492092940342.keychain CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS=/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/Entitlements1862900839419593581.plist
Executing: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath eCustMobileProto1.xcarchive -exportPath /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8025404516907269688xxx/result -exportOptionsPlist /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/export55737858647735041.plist -verbose PROVISIONING_PROFILE=8526205d-efbf-48ac-9ea4-bd8390742199 CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX KEYCHAIN=/Users/administrator/Library/Keychains/temp1492092940342.keychain CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS=/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/Entitlements1862900839419593581.plist 2017-04-13 09:19:19.520 xcodebuild[5905:89296095] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/eCustMobileProto1_2017-04-13_09-19-19.518.xcdistributionlogs'.
2017-04-13 09:19:19.547 xcodebuild[5905:89296095] [MT] DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%207.3.1.db).
2017-04-13 09:19:19.889 xcodebuild[5905:89296095] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionProvisioning _itemToSigningInfoMap:]: Can't find any applicable signing identities for items: (
    "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7f91c3a52830 'com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1' '<DVTFilePath:0x7f91c3e79d70:'/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8025404516907269688xxx/dist/eCustMobileProto1.xcarchive/Products/Applications/eCustMobileProto1.app'>'>"
)
Errors={
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c3a99150; name='iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX', hash='264A08D2D02101133916EE5C037EC6D122953369', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>" =     {
        "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7f91c3a52830 'com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1' '<DVTFilePath:0x7f91c3e79d70:'/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8025404516907269688xxx/dist/eCustMobileProto1.xcarchive/Products/Applications/eCustMobileProto1.app'>'>" = "Error Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=7 \"No matching provisioning profiles found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: keychain-access-groups, application-identifier, com.apple.developer.icloud-services, get-task-allow., NSLocalizedDescription=No matching provisioning profiles found, IDECodesignResolverError_ResolutionInputsKey=<IDECodesignResolutionInputs: 0x7f91c3a99390; portalTeamID='YYYYYYYYY', usingTeamBasedSigning='NO', bundleIdentifier='com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1', targetName='(null)', provisioningProfilePurpose='0', requiresProvisioningProfile='YES', provisioningProfilePlatform='iOS', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2', requiredEntitlements='{\n    \"application-identifier\" = \"YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile\";\n    \"com.apple.developer.icloud-services\" =     (\n        CloudDocuments\n    );\n    \"get-task-allow\" = 1;\n    \"keychain-access-groups\" =     (\n        \"YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile\"\n    );\n}', requiredCodesignableDevices='(null)', requiredFeatures='(null)'>\n}";
    };
}
2017-04-13 09:19:19.889 xcodebuild[5905:89296095] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7f91c3eb8590>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={IDEDistributionErrorSigningIdentityToItemToUnderlyingErrorKey={
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c3a99150; name='iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX', hash='264A08D2D02101133916EE5C037EC6D122953369', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>" =     {
        "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7f91c3a52830 'com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1' '<DVTFilePath:0x7f91c3e79d70:'/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8025404516907269688xxx/dist/eCustMobileProto1.xcarchive/Products/Applications/eCustMobileProto1.app'>'>" = "Error Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=7 \"No matching provisioning profiles found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: keychain-access-groups, application-identifier, com.apple.developer.icloud-services, get-task-allow., NSLocalizedDescription=No matching provisioning profiles found, IDECodesignResolverError_ResolutionInputsKey=<IDECodesignResolutionInputs: 0x7f91c3a99390; portalTeamID='YYYYYYYYY', usingTeamBasedSigning='NO', bundleIdentifier='com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1', targetName='(null)', provisioningProfilePurpose='0', requiresProvisioningProfile='YES', provisioningProfilePlatform='iOS', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2', requiredEntitlements='{\n    \"application-identifier\" = \"YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile\";\n    \"com.apple.developer.icloud-services\" =     (\n        CloudDocuments\n    );\n    \"get-task-allow\" = 1;\n    \"keychain-access-groups\" =     (\n        \"YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile\"\n    );\n}', requiredCodesignableDevices='(null)', requiredFeatures='(null)'>\n}";
    };
}}
error: exportArchive: The operation couldnâ€™t be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 3.)

Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={IDEDistributionErrorSigningIdentityToItemToUnderlyingErrorKey={
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c3a99150; name='iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX', hash='264A08D2D02101133916EE5C037EC6D122953369', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>" =     {
        "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7f91c3a52830 'com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1' '<DVTFilePath:0x7f91c3e79d70:'/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8025404516907269688xxx/dist/eCustMobileProto1.xcarchive/Products/Applications/eCustMobileProto1.app'>'>" = "Error Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=7 \"No matching provisioning profiles found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: keychain-access-groups, application-identifier, com.apple.developer.icloud-services, get-task-allow., NSLocalizedDescription=No matching provisioning profiles found, IDECodesignResolverError_ResolutionInputsKey=<IDECodesignResolutionInputs: 0x7f91c3a99390; portalTeamID='YYYYYYYYY', usingTeamBasedSigning='NO', bundleIdentifier='com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1', targetName='(null)', provisioningProfilePurpose='0', requiresProvisioningProfile='YES', provisioningProfilePlatform='iOS', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2', requiredEntitlements='{\n    \"application-identifier\" = \"YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile\";\n    \"com.apple.developer.icloud-services\" =     (\n        CloudDocuments\n    );\n    \"get-task-allow\" = 1;\n    \"keychain-access-groups\" =     (\n        \"YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile\"\n    );\n}', requiredCodesignableDevices='(null)', requiredFeatures='(null)'>\n}";
    };
}}

** EXPORT FAILED **

Failed export step
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] IDECodesignResolver parametersForInputs:applicableSigningIdentityCertificates:profileManager:logAspect:withError: inputs: <IDECodesignResolutionInputs: 0x7f91c3a99390; portalTeamID='YYYYYYYYY', usingTeamBasedSigning='NO', bundleIdentifier='com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1', targetName='(null)', provisioningProfilePurpose='0', requiresProvisioningProfile='YES', provisioningProfilePlatform='iOS', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2', requiredEntitlements='{
    "application-identifier" = "YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile";
    "com.apple.developer.icloud-services" =     (
        CloudDocuments
    );
    "get-task-allow" = 1;
    "keychain-access-groups" =     (
        "YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile"
    );
}', requiredCodesignableDevices='(null)', requiredFeatures='(null)'>
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] signing identities: (
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c3a99150; name='iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX', hash='264A08D2D02101133916EE5C037EC6D122953369', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>"
)
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] unexpired certificates: (
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c3a99150; name='iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX', hash='264A08D2D02101133916EE5C037EC6D122953369', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>"
)
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] iOS certificates: (
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c3a99150; name='iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX', hash='264A08D2D02101133916EE5C037EC6D122953369', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>"
)
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] unexpired signing identities: (
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c3a99150; name='iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX', hash='264A08D2D02101133916EE5C037EC6D122953369', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>"
)
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] iOS signing identities: (
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c3a99150; name='iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX', hash='264A08D2D02101133916EE5C037EC6D122953369', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>"
)
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] unexpired iOS signing identities: (
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c3a99150; name='iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX', hash='264A08D2D02101133916EE5C037EC6D122953369', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>"
)
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] allUsableProfiles: {(
    8526205d-efbf-48ac-9ea4-bd8390742199
)}
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] limiting to signing identities: {(
    <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c3a99150; name='iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX', hash='264A08D2D02101133916EE5C037EC6D122953369', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>
)}
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] profiles filtered by signing identities: {(
    8526205d-efbf-48ac-9ea4-bd8390742199
)}
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] profiles filtered by platform: {(
    8526205d-efbf-48ac-9ea4-bd8390742199
)}
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] profilesForTeam: {(
    8526205d-efbf-48ac-9ea4-bd8390742199
)}
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] profilesForBundleID: {(
    8526205d-efbf-48ac-9ea4-bd8390742199
)}
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] (intersection of the two): {(
    8526205d-efbf-48ac-9ea4-bd8390742199
)}
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] Filtering based on requested entitlements: {
    "application-identifier" = "YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile";
    "com.apple.developer.icloud-services" =     (
        CloudDocuments
    );
    "get-task-allow" = 1;
    "keychain-access-groups" =     (
        "YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile"
    );
}
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] Rejecting: 8526205d-efbf-48ac-9ea4-bd8390742199 (Offending Key: application-identifier)


2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] -[IDEDistributionProvisioning _itemToSigningInfoMap:]: Can't find any applicable signing identities for items: (
    "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7f91c3a52830 'com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1' '<DVTFilePath:0x7f91c3e79d70:'/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8025404516907269688xxx/dist/eCustMobileProto1.xcarchive/Products/Applications/eCustMobileProto1.app'>'>"
)
Errors={
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c3a99150; name='iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX', hash='264A08D2D02101133916EE5C037EC6D122953369', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>" =     {
        "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7f91c3a52830 'com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1' '<DVTFilePath:0x7f91c3e79d70:'/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8025404516907269688xxx/dist/eCustMobileProto1.xcarchive/Products/Applications/eCustMobileProto1.app'>'>" = "Error Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=7 \"No matching provisioning profiles found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: keychain-access-groups, application-identifier, com.apple.developer.icloud-services, get-task-allow., NSLocalizedDescription=No matching provisioning profiles found, IDECodesignResolverError_ResolutionInputsKey=<IDECodesignResolutionInputs: 0x7f91c3a99390; portalTeamID='YYYYYYYYY', usingTeamBasedSigning='NO', bundleIdentifier='com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1', targetName='(null)', provisioningProfilePurpose='0', requiresProvisioningProfile='YES', provisioningProfilePlatform='iOS', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2', requiredEntitlements='{\n    \"application-identifier\" = \"YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile\";\n    \"com.apple.developer.icloud-services\" =     (\n        CloudDocuments\n    );\n    \"get-task-allow\" = 1;\n    \"keychain-access-groups\" =     (\n        \"YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile\"\n    );\n}', requiredCodesignableDevices='(null)', requiredFeatures='(null)'>\n}";
    };
}
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7f91c3eb8590>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={IDEDistributionErrorSigningIdentityToItemToUnderlyingErrorKey={
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c3a99150; name='iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX', hash='264A08D2D02101133916EE5C037EC6D122953369', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>" =     {
        "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7f91c3a52830 'com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1' '<DVTFilePath:0x7f91c3e79d70:'/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8025404516907269688xxx/dist/eCustMobileProto1.xcarchive/Products/Applications/eCustMobileProto1.app'>'>" = "Error Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=7 \"No matching provisioning profiles found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: keychain-access-groups, application-identifier, com.apple.developer.icloud-services, get-task-allow., NSLocalizedDescription=No matching provisioning profiles found, IDECodesignResolverError_ResolutionInputsKey=<IDECodesignResolutionInputs: 0x7f91c3a99390; portalTeamID='YYYYYYYYY', usingTeamBasedSigning='NO', bundleIdentifier='com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1', targetName='(null)', provisioningProfilePurpose='0', requiresProvisioningProfile='YES', provisioningProfilePlatform='iOS', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2', requiredEntitlements='{\n    \"application-identifier\" = \"YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile\";\n    \"com.apple.developer.icloud-services\" =     (\n        CloudDocuments\n    );\n    \"get-task-allow\" = 1;\n    \"keychain-access-groups\" =     (\n        \"YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile\"\n    );\n}', requiredCodesignableDevices='(null)', requiredFeatures='(null)'>\n}";
    };
}}


2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] Running step: IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep with <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7f91c3a4bf20; archive(resolved)='<IDEArchive: 0x7f91c3e79390>', distributionTask(resolved)='2', distributionMethod(resolved)='<IDEDistributionMethodDevelopmentSigned: 0x7f91c3a44290>', teamID(resolved)='(null)'>
    Chain (2, self inclusive):
    <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7f91c3a4bf20; archive = '(null)', distributionMethod='<IDEDistributionMethodDevelopmentSigned: 0x7f91c3a44290>', teamID='(null)'>
    <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7f91c3e7a1c0; archive = '<IDEArchive: 0x7f91c3e79390>', distributionMethod='(null)', teamID='(null)'>
</IDEDistributionContext: 0x7f91c3a4bf20>


2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] Available distribution methods: (
    "<IDEDistributionMethodiOSAppStoreExport: 0x7f91c3a33630>",
    "<IDEDistributionMethodAdHoc: 0x7f91c3a41930>",
    "<IDEDistributionMethodEnterprise: 0x7f91c3a42da0>",
    "<IDEDistributionMethodDevelopmentSigned: 0x7f91c3a44290>"
)
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7f91c3e79d70:'/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8025404516907269688xxx/dist/eCustMobileProto1.xcarchive/Products/Applications/eCustMobileProto1.app'>
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] Set distributionItems on context: (
    "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7f91c3a52830 'com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1' '<DVTFilePath:0x7f91c3e79d70:'/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8025404516907269688xxx/dist/eCustMobileProto1.xcarchive/Products/Applications/eCustMobileProto1.app'>'>"
)
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] -[IDEDistributionProvisioning _itemToSigningInfoMap:]: Locating assets for items = (
    "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7f91c3a52830 'com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1' '<DVTFilePath:0x7f91c3e79d70:'/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8025404516907269688xxx/dist/eCustMobileProto1.xcarchive/Products/Applications/eCustMobileProto1.app'>'>"
)
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] Disqualifying <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c401cb70; name='iPhone Developer: Shai Almog (55H932G5NZ)', hash='80DA25654740E10EF2406159912AB9A75E3496C8', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'> due to teamID (input YYYYYYYYY doesn't match Q5GHSKAL2F)
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] Disqualifying <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c400be90; name='iPhone Distribution: Shai Almog (Q5GHSKAL2F)', hash='99CD340C9BEFB4C92B15A69A9D0F85811C2A0C6D', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4'> due to teamID (input YYYYYYYYY doesn't match Q5GHSKAL2F)
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] -[IDEDistributionProvisioning _signingCertificatesApplicableForTeamID:certificateKind:isForInstaller:error:]: identityCertificatesMatchingKind [kind=1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] = (
    "<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c3a99150; name='iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX', hash='264A08D2D02101133916EE5C037EC6D122953369', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>"
)
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] __93-[IDEDistributionProvisioning _itemToSigningInfoForSigningCertificate:flattenedItems:errors:]_block_invoke: Cannot locate provisioning info for item ('<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7f91c3a52830 'com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1' '<DVTFilePath:0x7f91c3e79d70:'/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8025404516907269688xxx/dist/eCustMobileProto1.xcarchive/Products/Applications/eCustMobileProto1.app'>'>') using identity '<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c3a99150; name='iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX', hash='264A08D2D02101133916EE5C037EC6D122953369', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>'. Error = Error Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=7 "No matching provisioning profiles found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: keychain-access-groups, application-identifier, com.apple.developer.icloud-services, get-task-allow., NSLocalizedDescription=No matching provisioning profiles found, IDECodesignResolverError_ResolutionInputsKey=<IDECodesignResolutionInputs: 0x7f91c3a99390; portalTeamID='YYYYYYYYY', usingTeamBasedSigning='NO', bundleIdentifier='com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1', targetName='(null)', provisioningProfilePurpose='0', requiresProvisioningProfile='YES', provisioningProfilePlatform='iOS', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2', requiredEntitlements='{
    "application-identifier" = "YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile";
    "com.apple.developer.icloud-services" =     (
        CloudDocuments
    );
    "get-task-allow" = 1;
    "keychain-access-groups" =     (
        "YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile"
    );
}', requiredCodesignableDevices='(null)', requiredFeatures='(null)'>
}
2017-04-13 14:19:19 +0000 [MT] -[IDEDistributionProvisioning _itemToSigningInfoMap:]: Errors finding items for signing identity (<DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f91c3a99150; name='iPhone Developer: XXXXXXXXX', hash='264A08D2D02101133916EE5C037EC6D122953369', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>) = {
    "<IDEDistributionItem: 0x7f91c3a52830 'com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1' '<DVTFilePath:0x7f91c3e79d70:'/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8025404516907269688xxx/dist/eCustMobileProto1.xcarchive/Products/Applications/eCustMobileProto1.app'>'>" = "Error Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=7 \"No matching provisioning profiles found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: keychain-access-groups, application-identifier, com.apple.developer.icloud-services, get-task-allow., NSLocalizedDescription=No matching provisioning profiles found, IDECodesignResolverError_ResolutionInputsKey=<IDECodesignResolutionInputs: 0x7f91c3a99390; portalTeamID='YYYYYYYYY', usingTeamBasedSigning='NO', bundleIdentifier='com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1', targetName='(null)', provisioningProfilePurpose='0', requiresProvisioningProfile='YES', provisioningProfilePlatform='iOS', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2', requiredEntitlements='{\n    \"application-identifier\" = \"YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile\";\n    \"com.apple.developer.icloud-services\" =     (\n        CloudDocuments\n    );\n    \"get-task-allow\" = 1;\n    \"keychain-access-groups\" =     (\n        \"YYYYYYYYY.com.selisys.eCustMobile\"\n    );\n}', requiredCodesignableDevices='(null)', requiredFeatures='(null)'>\n}";
}
```

And there is the codenameone_settings.properties where the build hints are:

```
#
#Thu Apr 13 16:16:44 CEST 2017
codename1.ios.appid=XXXXXXXX.com.selisys.eCustMobile
codename1.ios.release.provision=C\:\\dev\\eCustMobile_distribution.mobileprovision
codename1.arg.java.version=8
codename1.arg.ios.objC=true
codename1.arg.ios.icloud.CloudDocuments=true
codename1.j2me.nativeTheme=nativej2me.res
codename1.arg.ios.project_type=ios
codename1.arg.ios.interface_orientation=UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait\:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown\:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft\:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
codename1.displayName=eCustMobile
codename1.arg.ios.pods.platform=7.0
codename1.android.keystoreAlias=lsitCN1
codename1.arg.android.xapplication=<meta-data     android\:name\="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"     android\:value\="MyApiKeyAndroid"/>
codename1.ios.release.certificate=C\:\\dev\\eCustMobile_distribution.p12
codename1.android.keystorePassword=XXXXXXX
codename1.ios.provision=
codename1.arg.ios.add_libs=SystemConfiguration.framework
codename1.arg.ios.glAppDelegateHeader=\n\#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"
codename1.arg.ios.afterFinishLaunching=[GMSServices provideAPIKey\:@"MyApiKeyiOS"];
codename1.languageLevel=5
codename1.android.keystore=C\:\\Users\\Gauvain\\Keychain.ks
codename1.arg.ios.pods=,GoogleMaps
codename1.vendor=CodenameOne
codename1.arg.ios.locationUsageDescription=Used to locates technician on interventions
codename1.arg.android.playService.maps=true
codename1.ios.certificatePassword=
codename1.ios.debug.certificatePassword=password
codename1.mainName=eCustMobileProto1
codename1.arg.ios.pods.sources=,https\://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
codename1.ios.release.certificatePassword=password
codename1.arg.ios.prerendered_icon=true
codename1.arg.ios.debug.distributionMethod=development
codename1.ios.debug.certificate=C\:\\dev\\eCustMobile_development.p12
libVersion=158
codename1.arg.android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> <uses-permission android\:name\="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/><uses-feature         android\:glEsVersion\="0x00020000"         android\:required\="true"/>
codename1.description=eCUST Mobile
codename1.secondaryTitle=eCustMobileProto1
codename1.ios.debug.provision=C\:\\dev\\eCustMobile_development.mobileprovision
codename1.rim.certificatePassword=
codename1.version=0.30
codename1.ios.certificate=
codename1.icon=icon.png
codename1.rim.signtoolCsk=
codename1.rim.signtoolDb=
codename1.arg.ios.includePush=false
codename1.packageName=com.selisys.eCustMobileProto1
```

Sorry if any presentation mistakes or so, it's my first SO post !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your AppID includes CloudKit support.  This is required for the filechooser library.

[image]

There is a note about this in the [installation instructions for the lib](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-filechooser#installation).

Comment: Thank you very much, it just builded successfully ! :)