# Xcode 9.2 error

Tags: codenameone

I've tried to launch an iOS debug build last friday (so after the Xcode 9.2 by default) and the build process failed with following message :

```
Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "exportOptionsPlist error for key 'iCloudContainerEnvironment': expected one of {Development, Production}, but no value was provided" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=exportOptionsPlist error for key 'iCloudContainerEnvironment': expected one of {Development, Production}, but no value was provided}

** EXPORT FAILED **

Process return code is 70
```

I've fixed this by forcing build with 7.3, but is it a way to fix this error from my side ? I don't like the idea to not use the latest version if it's available.

Comment: I haven't run into this myself, are you using a cn1llib that requires icloud such as file chooser?

Comment: I'm using file chooser, so I need to add some build hints I suppose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you set up the App ID in Apple Developer.  The settings should look like
[image]

Notice that is should be associated with zero cloud containers.

Comment: It's exactly configured like that, I've already had problems about this library several month ago, and you provide me this answer back then (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43395387/codename-one-ios-build-error-at-export-step)

Comment: I have reproduced the issue and have applied a patch to the build server for xcode 9.2 builds to include the appropriate options in the export options plist.  This will be included in the next update tomorrow (Friday)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it monday :)